# Possible z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index

It seems that my dropdown menu its z-index is doing something strange:

https://uma.be/evenement/uma-day-2020-best-media-campaigns/

When you hover the menu-item "Commissions", the dropdown menu goes underneath the image.

[image: issue screenshot]

I've already checked the z-index of the image itself and the z-index of `.mega-sub-menu`. Both seems okay to me. The class `.mega-sub-menu` has an z-index of 999 and the image hasn't got one.

I've added `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to the image, but that didn't fix the issue.

Is it possible that the Lazy loader does something with the image so that it goes over the sub navigation?

Comment: Give **#wrapper-navbar** a higher z-index. It currently has 1, same as **#tribe-events-content**

Comment: `#wrapper-navbar {z-index: 2}` fixes it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your image and the menu are not in the same stacking context. To ensure that they are in the same stacking context, you will need to find out the parent element of both elements that are siblings to each other.

In this case, that will be:

- `#wrapper-navbar` as the parent element for the dropdown menu
- `#tribe-events-pg-template` as the parent element for the contents of the page (which includes the image)

All you need to do is:

1. Set the z-index of `#wrapper-navbar` to `2`
2. Relatively position `#tribe-events-pg-template` and set its z-index to `1`

Updated CSS:

```
#wrapper-navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
#tribe-events-pg-template {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

After fix is applied:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your #navbar's z-index property. Increase it or remove it and that should fix your problem
>

```
 #wrapper-navbar {
     position: relative;
     /* z-index: 1; */ 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following (added the z-index and position):

```
#tribe-events-pg-template, .tribe-events-pg-template {
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;}
```